# How to install CouchDB plugin/daemon like couchperuser

Tags: plugins, couchdb, daemon

How can one install a CouchDB plugin/daemon like [couchperuser](https://github.com/etrepum/couchperuser)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install any dependencies. *couchperuser* requires *rebar*, e.g.

```
$ brew install rebar
```

Ensure the plugin directory exists, e.g.

```
$ mkdir /usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.0_1/lib/couchdb/plugins
```

Clone (download) the repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/etrepum/couchperuser.git
```

Move the plugin files:

```
$ mv couchperuser /usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.0_1/lib/couchdb/plugins
```

Build the plugin files:

```
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/couchdb/1.6.0_1/lib/couchdb/plugins/couchperuser
$ make
```

Restart couchdb

Comment: Hi! How to install `couchpereuser` in ubuntu installation?